# Getting Post Permalink By Post Id Doesn't Work

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Wordpress blog I am trying to get post permalink of a post of custom post type for which I add this code to function.php

```
function get_randomp() { ?>
<?php 
$args=array('post_type'=>'photo', 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page'=>'1'); 
$photo=new WP_Query($args); while ($photo->have_posts()) : $photo->the_post();
?>
<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<?php } ?>
```

and this added this code in sidebar.php to output the permalink,

```
<?php 
$postidr = get_randomp();
echo get_permalink( $postidr ); 
?>
```

But it is showing permalink of the current post which is being viewed.
Please help me guys.

Comment: I can't see anything in `get_randomp` that returns a value. Instead of echoing `get_the_ID`, you need to assign it to a variable; and `return` that at the end of the the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working code is here, put this into your theme functions.php

```
function get_randomp() { 

$args=array('post_type'=>'photo', 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page'=>'1'); 
$photo=new WP_Query($args); while ($photo->have_posts()) : $photo->the_post();


echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">';
echo 'Link';
echo '</a>';

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'get_randomp',1);
```

and call it as `get_randomp();` wherever you want

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, it worked perfectly well but I need one more help please help me.

Actually I want to output the permalink in sidebar and want to show a custom field "upload-photo" of the same random post in footer, please tell me how that can be done.

Thanks once again

Comment: if my answer is correct then accept it as by tick it as right

Comment: what you mean 'upload-photo' custom field? i can't get your words

Comment: I mean I want to show the permalink of that post in side bar of the blog and want to get value from 'upload-photo' custom field in footer of the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Your function shouldn't echo the result, rather it should return it. You also have very malformed code, try this instead:

```
function get_randomp() { 
    $args = array('post_type'=>'photo', 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page'=>'1'); 
    $photos = new WP_Query($args); // Posts set to variable

    $photo = current($photos); // Get first, and only, post

    wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset posts

    return $photo->ID; // Return ID from post object
}
```

Comment: Added your code to function.php and echo get_randomp(); to sidebar.php  but got no output